# typescript option type valid for null value interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like this

```
export interface Font {
  id: number
  table_definition_id: number
  auth: boolean | null
```

The interface always have key `auth` with value boolean or null

If I change it to

```
export interface Font {
  id: number
  table_definition_id: number
  auth?: boolean 
}
```

Will this be valid?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be valid because then auth could be either boolean or undefined, never null